# Load scripts only for selected template

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

Is there a built in function to load scripts only for particular template?

At them moment I am doing like so:

```
if (is_page('portfolio') || is_page('gallery')){

wp_register_script('jScrollpane', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jScrollpane');
}
```

and it works as long as I call the pages "portfolio" and "gallery". I would like to have it more reusable, how can I achieve that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you define _"reusable"_ in context with what you mean?  Explain how you would envision it working, and maybe we can help.

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear...lucky for me Pippin gave the answer I needed. I want the final user to be free to call the pages whatever he wants and just select template "Portfolio" of "Gallery" based on his needs. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: I suggest reading this excellent post on loading js in WordPress: http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `is_page_template('template.php')` and just replace template.php with your template name.